# Lift of Dirichlet characters - specific example

Tags: modular-arithmetic, characters

I'm trying to understand the process of lifting a Dirichlet character $ \chi$, where a Dirichlet character modulo $N$ being defined as a homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z})^*$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Now my book states that I lift a Dirichlet character  as follows and gives also an example on how this works: 
[image]

However, the distribution of these elements seems purely abitrary to me and I simply cannot see the logic behind this (Maybe there is more to the process of lifting a Dirichlet character than I grasped from this explanation). It would be amazing if anyone could help me out! Thanks!

Comment: First try to understand the projection.

Comment: I think it means that I'm sending an element $x$ mod $N$ to the element $x$ mod $d$ and I can do this because I know that $d$ divides $N$. (Am I right?) However, I'm still clueless about the example above...

Comment: What does the projection do with the elements for $N=12, D=4

Comment: Ah, thank you! It sends $1$ and $5$ mod $12$ to $1$ mod $4$ and $7$ and $11$ mod $12$ to $3$ mod $4$ and if I then use that the Dirichlet character mod $4$ takes $1$ to $1$ and $3$ to $-1$, I get the result. Still one question: Am I right using then that $(\mathbb{Z}/ 4 \mathbb{Z})^*= \{1,3\}= \{3^2,3^1 \}$ and thus $\chi(1)= \chi(3)^2, \chi(3)= \chi(3)$ and as $\chi(1)=1$ always, I get that $\chi(3)^2=\chi(3^2)=\chi(1)=1$ and $\chi(3)=-1$ as it has to be a square root of $1$.

Answer (score 4):

I really don't like how Dirichlet characters are introduced in number theory books. Tell me if this makes more sense to you :

- Dirichlet character : completely multiplicative and $m$ periodic
- If $\chi$ is a  Dirichlet character modulo $d$ then $\psi(n) = \chi(n) 1_{\gcd(n,k)=1}$ is the product of two Dirichlet characters modulo $d$ and $k$ thus is a Dirichlet character modulo $m = \text{lcm}(d,k)$.
- Write $m= \prod_{j=1}^l p_j^{e_j}$. By the Chinese remainder theorem, for every residue classes $a_j \bmod p_j^{e_j}$ there exists $b \bmod m$ such that $\forall j, b \equiv a_j \bmod p_j^{e_j}$. Therefore any $\chi$ modulo $m$ decomposes uniquely as $\chi = \prod_{j=1}^l \chi_{p_j^{e_j}}$ where $\chi_{p_i^{e_i}}$ is a Dirichlet character modulo $p_i^{e_j}$ defined by $\chi_{p_i^{e_i}}(n) = \chi(b)$ with $b \equiv n \bmod p_i^{e_i}, \forall j \ne i, b \equiv 1 \bmod p_j^{e_j}$.
- $\chi$ is primitive means none of the $\chi_{p_i^{e_i}}$ is the trivial character $1_{\gcd(n,p_i)=1}$.
- That is to say for $\gcd(m,k)=1$, the map $(\chi, \varphi) \mapsto \chi\varphi$ is an isomorphism from the pair of Dirichlet characters modulo $m,k$ to the Dirichlet characters modulo $mk$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm fairly new to the field of Dirichlet characters and your post gives me some very helpful insights (and a different point of view) on them.